# Woocommerce: How to design the inner square of a select field?

Tags: html, css, select, woocommerce

I'm working on a woocommerce site and have some issues with the select-field.
As you can see on the image the inner square will not be designed when I define the `<select>` field in CSS and/or the class.

What am I missing when I'm trying to design the Select-field?

The css:

```
    .country_select {
    width: 50% !important;
    text-align: left;
    background: f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

The HTML-code 
(I removed a big part of the `<option>` choices)

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
        <p class="form-row form-row form-row-wide address-field update_totals_on_change form-group validate-required" id="billing_country_field">
<label for="billing_country" class="">Land <abbr class="required" title="krävs">*</abbr></label>
<select name="billing_country" id="billing_country" autocomplete="country" class="country_to_state country_select input-value" ><option value="">Välj land&hellip;</option><option value="AX" >Danmark</option></select><noscript><input type="submit" name="woocommerce_checkout_update_totals" value="Uppdatera land" /></noscript></p>       </div>
        </div>
```

The result (image):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nothing, I think it's because you have a misspelling in your CSS.

Just change

```
 background: f1f1f1;
```

to

```
 background: #f1f1f1;
```